# swing components not showing up in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to load some images in a scrollable pane. But for some reason it is not showing up. Here is my piece of code to add Images.

```
 private JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(){
        @Override
        public void approveSelection(){
            File files[] = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(files.length, 1));
            for(int lop=0; lop< files.length; lop++){

                BufferedImage image = null;
                try {                
                    image = ImageIO.read(files[lop]);
                } catch (IOException ex) {}
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, 1);
                Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
                g.dispose();

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                JLabel lable = new JLabel(icon);
                panel.add(lable);    

            }
            jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(panel);    
            super.approveSelection();
        }
    };
```

Using above fileCHooser, I select some images to load in a vertical scrollPane, somehow, scrollPane horizontal scroller shows up change in length, but there are no contents in the scrollpane. Please check following screenshot. under the title of Shapes: you will see an empty container with extended scrollbars

[image: Screenshot]

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: *"swing components not showing up in JScrollPane"* Gee I don't think that has ever happened ..this hour.  Perhaps twice in the last day though.  Please search in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(new JFrame().add(panel));
```

Why do you create a JFrame?

You should just create the JScrollPane like this:

```
jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Or set the view of the scrollpane like this:

```
jScrollpane.setViewportView(panel);
```

Also, you should just use `panel.add(lable)`. The GridLayout will put the label at the appropriate location.
And you should not ignore exceptions. Transform the empty catch block to:

```
try {                
    image = ImageIO.read(files[lop]);
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post to 
jScrollpane.setViewportView(panel);

it is not even working that way. I was just trying a solution that way. Thnxs